# How get langtitude and latitude from expo-location?(from Object{ } )

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native, expo

I need to take the exact numbers from the object, that is, the langtitude and latitude of the current location, so that I can use it outside the hook as a variable

```
useEffect(() => {
        (async () => {
          let { status } = await Location.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync();
          if (status !== 'granted') {
            setErrorMsg('Permission to access location was denied');
          }
    
          Location.setGoogleApiKey(apiKey);
    
          console.log(status);
    
          let { coords } = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({});
      
          setLocation(coords);
    
          console.log(coords);
    
          if (coords) {
            let { longitude, latitude } = coords;
    
            let regionName = await Location.reverseGeocodeAsync({
              longitude,
              latitude,
            });
            let long = await {
              longitude,
              latitude,
            };
            setAddress(regionName[0]);
            //console.log(regionName, 'nothing'); 
            setLong(coords);
          }
```

[image]

Comment: What line of code does the image correspond to?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what the problem is. Could you explain more details? What are you trying to achieve, where does it fail?

Answer (score 0):

I have to ask, is the screenshot a result of your actual terminal values returned from console log. When I run:

`let location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync...`

and further below

`console.log(location)`

in my terminal it looks like this:

[image: screenshot of my terminal]

I saved the object returned by Expo Locations API in a variable named location, and in your case it seems like you named it coords.

This image tells me that `location` returns an object called `"coords"` and in your case judging by your screenshot, its called `Object`, but I have a hard time believing this is your screenshot, and just an example from somewhere perhaps.

Now to answer your question:

If I want to store something or console log anything from my object using `locations`, I would type for example:

`let altitudeAccuracy = location.coords.altitudeAccuracy`

or

`let myLat = location.coords.latitude`

or

```
console.log(location.coords.longitude)
```

In you case, it would maybe look something like:

`let lat = coords.coords.latitude`

and

`let lon = coords.coords.longitude`

Console log your coords you get from the API and then pay attention to what it returns in the terminal and use that to access objects within objects and properties within objects.

Best of luck! I know i'm a year late but hopefully it helps someone who is in our shoes not long ago!